# Restler with Cucumber

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, restler

I am totally new with protractor/cucumber and restler. I am using Typescript. Below is the code that I am using to hit the endpoint url and to get the response

```
Given('Hit the {string}', async (string) => {
  browser.quit()
  var data: any = get(string.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  console.log("In method:" + string.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  console.log(data.response);
});
```

---

### This prints the below:

In method:endpoint URL

### undefined

I want the response and the responsecode to be printed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the restler package but it could be an async issue. Try this `console.log(await data.response);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. Below code worked

```
Given('Hit the {string}', async (endpointUrl) => {
    await get(endpointUrl).on('complete', async (result, response) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    });
});
```